# How do you access the public properties and methods of a loaded SWF

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

How would you go about calling the public properties and methods of a SWF you load in actionscript?

I have been using stackoverflow for years to answer my programming questions so I wanted to give back by writing a guide to an issue I had a lot of trouble figuring out. This is my first user guide so tell me if there is anything I can do to improve it.

Comment: Admiring the sentiment. :) Rather than posting a "user guide", though, I believe the accepted way of doing this is to ask a question and then post your own answer.

Comment: Also, this guide is for AIR only -> File and FileSteam are AIR only classes. Try maybe replacing with URLLoader with the dataFormat set to URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY

Comment: Yeah, I suggest re-writing this as a question, then posting your solution as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on my formatting. I also mentioned that you can use a URLStream instead of a FileStream.

Comment: +1 for reworking your question / answer approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the more powerful features of the flash engine is the ability to load flash programs within flash programs, through the use of the Loader class. Unfortunately communication with the loaded program is limited. While you can establish a LocalConnection object there is a limit to the traffic it can safely support.

A simple solution is to load the SWF file within your main program’s security domain. This has the benefit of exposing the public methods and properties of the loaded SWF to the loader and vice versa.

First extend the Loader class this class will be used to interact with the loaded file.

```
public class ParentChildLoader extends Loader
```

Next we must store the SWF file as a ByteArray. The variable path is a file path on the system. You could use a URLStream object instead of a FileStream for a http url.

```
var swfBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var file:File = new File(path);
if (file.exists)
{
    var loadStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    loadStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    loadStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
    loadStream.close();
}
```

Now that we have the SWF stored as a ByteArray, we load the SWF into our security domain and listen for the complete event.

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoad);
loadBytes(swfBytes, context);
```

If you want to access the loaded SWF’s properties from the loader use the content property.

```
Object(this.content).foo(bar);
Object(this.content).a = b;
```

If you want to access the loader’s public properties from the SWF use the parent property.

```
Object(this.parent).foo(bar);
Object(this.parent).a = b;
```

This has many practical applications from allowing re-usability of common functions to taking some of the programming load off your creative team. A note of caution; the loaded SWF exists within your main program’s security domain so it is key that you only load files which you trust with this method.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be to use interfaces. Here's an example. Consists of two projects. Project 1 (PluginLoader) is your base app. Part of this project includes an AS3 Interface:

```
/* IPlugin.as */
package
    {
        public interface IPlugin
        {
            function getID():String;
            function doStuff():void;
        }
    }
```

Then, your loaded swf in a second project (TestPlugin) implements the interface:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestPlugin extends Sprite implements IPlugin
    {
        private const _ID:String = "TestPlugin";

        public function getID():String {
            return _ID;
        }

        public function doStuff():void {

            trace('Test plugin: Doing Stuff');
        }
    }
}
```

The interface would be included in that project via source files or swc.

Then to load it (back in PluginLoader project):

```
    public class PluginLoader extends Sprite
    {
        public function PluginLoader()
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader.load(new URLRequest('plugins/TestPlugin.swf'));
        }

        private function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
            var plugin:IPlugin = e.target.content as IPlugin;
            trace(plugin.getID());
            plugin.doStuff();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this method work with SWF files created in Creative Studio?

Comment: Hrm I will have to look into it. The whole point of the system is to take the onus of programming off of the creative team.

Comment: would using a swc module be more prudent? They are designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't want to add a library of functions to content. I want the content to talk directly to the loader.

Comment: I looked into your solution that is actually the reverse of what I need to do. I don't need the loader accessing functions of the content. I need the content accessing functions of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to disagree with you on your approach.  It is 'hackish' in my opinion.  There is a reason why you have limited communication with loaded swfs, and that is because you don't know what they do and how they're suppose to be managed.

If you want to talk architecturally, this is a very bad way of trying to access information.  The main application should not have to access properties within the loaded swf.  If you're building a large scale application and the loaded swf (a module maybe?) needs information that the main app has, you should look into an application framework like Parsley which does dependency injection to give the data your loaded swf needs.  It is a much cleaner approach and is architecturally sound.

Comment: I agree with you for most circumstances. The reason why I developed this was to remove the need of writing code from a group of creative designers. Basically it presents an API of functions that they could call from inside their ad content (ie dynamic feeds) without having to worry about importing libraries. Also so we could update the behavior of the functions without recompiling the content.